# devise authentication with http basic authentication OR cookie

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

I am trying to type an authentication method for my rails application that work as a backend API.

I have typed the following method to do so using devise and warden, and is working perfectly with cookies. however, I want to add the functionality that user should be able to authenticate via cookie-stored token, **or** via http basic authentication.

The code I have so far is:

```
def authenticated
    if warden.authenticated?
        return true
    elsif params[:access_token] 
      and User.find_for_token_authentication("access_token" => params[:access_token])
        return true
    elsif params[:xapp_token]
      and AccessGrant.find_access(params[:xapp_token])
        return true
    else
        error!('401 Unauthorized', 401)
    end
end
```

Could someone please help me with where and how to enable the http authentication as a substitiute to token authentication? so user can send eaither a token in a cookie or do a HTTP basic authentication??

Thanks in advance.